# Robot framework - Red Editor - Unknown library error message

Tags: robotframework, jython

I'm trying to import some classes using the "Library" keyword. I get the error message:

> "Unknown  library. Try to use Quick Fix (Ctrl+1) or add
>   library to red.xml for proper validation

Some of these classes exist in the same folder, other exists in another one. But same error for both cases.

<kbd>ctrl+1</kbd> doesn't help, it shows this error message:

> "Additional info: ((u"Importing test library '' failed:
>   ImportError: No module named infra".

And I'm not sure where to add to red.xml.

Any idea how to import classes and fix this error?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the Nokia RED guide there is a small section on RED.xml and the [Referenced Libraries tab](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/working_with_RED/red_xml.html#referenced-libraries-tab) that RED uses to map a library to it's python code.